# How play an AnimationClip in Unity3d?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, objectanimator

In Unity 3D, a model has add Component animator with enough data.

i get all AnimationClips by animator's `runtimeAnimatorController`

just like this:

```
AnimatorOverrideController aoc = new AnimatorOverrideController ( );
aoc.runtimeAnimatorController = SeletedRole.GetComponent<Animator> ( ).runtimeAnimatorController;
if ( acp.overrideClip != null )
{
   aniList.Add (acp.overrideClip);
   EditorGUILayout.LabelField ( acp.overrideClip.name );
   if ( GUILayout.Button ( acp.overrideClip.name ) )
   {
      AniName = acp.overrideClip.name;
      //SeletedRole.GetComponent<Animator> ( );
      //seletedRole is a model
   }
}
if(acp.originalClip!=null)
{
   aniList.Add ( acp.originalClip );

   if ( GUILayout.Button ( acp.originalClip.name ) )
   {
      AniName = acp.originalClip.name;
      //Animator animator=SeletedRole.GetComponent<Animator> ( );
   }
}
```

How to make the model play this clip,when i click on its' name  ?